# Access appsettings from an abstract class used in my test scripts

Tags: json, unit-testing, asp.net-core

Working with asp.net core 2.0

I have created a BD test project.

I have an abstract base class structured like this:

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
[Category("Integration")]
public abstract class BaseIntegrationContext : BaseIntegrationSetUp
{
    protected MyDataBaseContext Context;
    private IWebHostBuilder _webHostBuilder;

    protected override void FixtureSetUp()
    {
        base.FixtureSetUp();
        WebSetUp();
        DbSetUp();
    }

    private void WebSetUp()
    {
        _webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }

    private void DbSetUp()
    {
        base.FixtureSetUp();

        //options
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<InformedWorkerDbContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
            .Options;


        Context = new MyDataBaseContext(options);
    }
}
```

unless I copy and add the appsettings.json to this test project I will obviously get the error that the json file cannot be found.

What is the accepted way to access appsettings.json from withing an abstract base class that use in a test project?

I have tried adding an entity model called ServiceSettings that maps to the json file in my web project:

```
public class ServiceSettings
{
    public string DatabaseServerConnection { get; set; }
}
```

which i instantiate in startup.cs:

```
services.Configure<ServiceSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("ServiceSettings"));
```

My Json file looks like this:

```
{
  "ServiceSettings": {
    "DatabaseServerConnection": "Server=localhost;Initial,Catalog=InformedWorker;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },



  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information"
    },
    "Console": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Internal": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Razor": "Debug",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "Error",
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and in my abstract class I do this:

```
 IOptions<ServiceSettings> myOptions = Options.Create(new ServiceSettings()
    {

    });
```

but typing myOptions the intellisense only gives me 'Value' to work with..?

Answer (score 0):

> unless I copy and add the appsettings.json to this test project I will obviously get the error that the json file cannot be found.

This is cause you don't specify file location in

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
```

`.AddJsonFile` registers a JSON FileProvider and path parameter ("appsettings.json" in your case) is a Path relative to the base path stored in `ConfigurationBuilder.Properties`. So the default base path is null and a file is expected in current working directory.

To set base path you may use `.SetBasePath(<basePath>)` extension method

```
public static IConfigurationBuilder SetBasePath(this IConfigurationBuilder builder, string basePath);
```

where `basePath`: The absolute path of file-based providers.